# Joining Geometry and removing internal faces

Tags: mesh

I've got this model from Mecabrick that I would like to have as a character, however this model is split into multiple parts with a lot of internal geometry. I'm struggling to find a way to combine all this geometry into one mesh whilst also only having the visible parts be included.

You can see in the picture below that this model has lots of interior parts where actual lego would snap together, but I just want to remove it all and have one mesh. Is this possible without manually removing and rejoining every face from the mesh?
[image: Internal components]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I see is to go and manually fill all the holes. It's just a matter of hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> with the entire internal geometry selected.

You could then use a Boolean modifier to combine all the parts into one mesh, which will make it (pretty much) a single watertight mesh